# How to list the namespaces of a Citrusleaf/AeroSpike host?

Tags: database, nosql, key-value-store, aerospike

I want to list the namespaces on a host remotely using the C# Client SDK, and the documentation is very scarce about it.

I am aware of a server tool to do this but I need to query that from a maintenance tool that I am writing, so using the server console is not an option.

Does anybody know if this is possible and if so how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can make an info call with the string "namespaces" and parse the returned value.
doc on c# info API: http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/csharp/html/Methods_T_Aerospike_Client_Info.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can get that information by emulating the logic that clmonitor utilizes to communicate with the Aerospike cluster. Clmonitor is written in Python; executing the 'info' command in clmonitor provides a wealth of information, a subset of which is the list of namespaces. I suggest that you emulate the logic used by clmonitor in your C# code to communicate with the cluster and then parse out the information that you require. In the future, I suggest that you take advantage of the [Aerospike forums](https://forums.aerospike.com) to ask questions about Aerospike. Thank you for your interest in Aerospike.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Where can I find the clmonitor? on the python SDK?

Comment: clmonitor is part of the citrusleaf-tools / aerospike-tools package.